# IPv6 lookup data structure

Tags: data-structures, ipv6, ipv4, trie

A patricia trie is the well-know, [recommended data structure](http://search.cpan.org/~plonka/Net-Patricia-1.014/Patricia.pm#DESCRIPTION) for storing IPv4 allocations/assignments and performing lookup.

Is this true for IPv6 adddresses too? Just a deeper/taller trie to accommodate the extra 96 bits? Is the trie still patricia, or a different radix trie?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still use Patricia tries with a bigger depth, but the problem is the performance degrades linearly with the trie depth.
Designing specialized data structures for IPv6 lookup is an active field. Recent publications include:

- [A Dynamic Binary Hash Scheme for IPv6 Lookup](http://cial.csie.ncku.edu.tw/presentation/group_pdf/A%20Dynamic%20Binary%20Hash%20Scheme%20for%20IPv6%20Lookup.pdf) (PDF)
- [IPv6 Lookups using Distributed and Load Balanced Bloom Filters for 100Gbps Core Router Line Cards](http://www.arl.wustl.edu/~hs1/publication/iplookup2.pdf) (PDF)
- [FlashTrie: Hash-based Preﬁx-Compressed Trie for IP Route Lookup Beyond 100Gbps](http://eeweb.poly.edu/bando/publications/FlashTrie%28Infocom2010%29.pdf) (PDF)

I don't know of any available (open source) implementations of these data structures.